# What is the transparencyd daemon for?

Tags: macos

**transparencyd** seems to be there since macOS Catalina.
I cannot find any information about it other than what the MAN pages say :

```
"transparencyd is a system daemon that verifies transparency information 
for requesting clients. It is not intended to be invoked directly"
```

It occasionally tries to connect to server kt-prod.apple.com (17.56.48.13) via TCP/443

and some files in ~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.transparencyd:

[image]

What is the transparencyd daemon for?

Comment: Hopefully I guessed your question. I’ll edit it into the body so people know at the end the question in case the title changes...  some people here are cranky if there isn’t a clear question in the body of the text

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Question was of course in the title so to me there was no need to repeat it in the body. I thought it was obvious. I'll pay attention to this next time.

Comment: You do you,  just was explaining the possible reason for the down vote.

Comment: I just want to know why this app requires network access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It handles the API and SDK calls for developers to check user tracking entitlements and transparently request access to private data and set these preferences on a per-app and per-device basis.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency

Since 2010, Apple publicly has maintained that all privacy and tracking should be after we consent to what / how and when out data is accessed.

- https://daringfireball.net/linked/2020/12/18/steve-jobs-on-privacy

There’s a lot of public angst now that the code has shipped and is being enforced - not everyone is a fan of informed consent and opting in to tracking or “transparency”.

- https://daringfireball.net/linked/2020/12/18/swisher-facebook-apple
- https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2020/12/facebooks-laughable-campaign-against-apple-really-against-users-and-small

But to address your question, it’s the mechanism by which an application receives access to photos, contacts, files and other things by requesting that access from the operating system.

Comment: Also, I’m not here to defend Apple or cut down Facebook - and the spin may be hard to get past without some critical thinking.  Definitely read my links carefully and spend some time looking at the “free” apps and where you spend your money and time. With Apple, I tend to know how they make money on me and most services I don’t pay for directly are harder to sort out. Not all things you pay for are good, clearly, but funding an app is expensive and few do it for free these days. Certainly not at scale.

Comment: From what I understand of the App Tracking Transpacency, this seems be something for iOS 14, and for macOS Big Sur. I noticed and located the App Tracking on my iPhone ("Ask Permission to Track"). But my mac is on Catalina, so I wonder why that daemon runs there.

My follow-up question was going to be: what harm woud there be if I block that traffic on my mac. I am doing it, and so far don't notice any adverse effects.

Comment: One question per question is best @erratic . Ask away and link here if they are related questions.