# Can the transparencyd daemon traffic be dropped without adverse effects?

Tags: macos, catalina, privacy, firewall

Based on what the `transparencyd` daemon is for (explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409349/what-is-the-transparencyd-daemon-for/)) I have the impression so far there is no harm in blocking that traffic. Until now, every time my firewall drew my attention onto that outbound trancparencyd traffic, I blocked it and experienced no adverse effects.

Am I missing something, or is there indeed no harm in blocking `transparencyd` traffic?

(I am on Catalina. Perhaps things got worse in Big Sur.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the questions was asked I have systematically blocked all the transparencyd traffic, and have not experienced any adverse side effects.

Comment: Do you approve everything that asks to get full disk access (or deny across the board)? Thanks for documenting and testing this out “real world” style.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. The only "thing" that has full disk access is my anti-virus app. (in the Security & Privacy system preferences). Regarding transparencyd I just have Little Snitch block the traffic.